# XPath to exclude nodes that match multiple potential values

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML of Jobs and am trying to write an XPath 1.0 Query to filter/exlcude out any jobs that match a certain job set of job titles .

Here is my XPath:

`/jobs/job[Title[not(contains(text(),'Senior') or contains(text(),'Head Of Finance') or contains(text(),'Manager'))]]`

It appears to exclude jobs with 'Senior', i.e. 'Audit Senior', but jobs with the title 'Head of Finance' still appear - below is a snippet of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<jobs>
  <job>
    <JobId>3706463</JobId>
    <Category><![CDATA[Health ]]></Category>
    <Views>0</Views>
    <Apps>0</Apps>
    <Title><![CDATA[Head of Finance]]></Title>
    <JobTitleFacet><![CDATA[Finance Manager ]]></JobTitleFacet>
    <Hours><![CDATA[Full Time ]]></Hours>
    <ExperienceLevels><![CDATA[PQ]]></ExperienceLevels>
  </job>
   <job>
    <JobId>3706459</JobId>
    <Views>0</Views>
    <Apps>0</Apps>
    <Title><![CDATA[Audit Senior]]></Title>
    <JobTitleFacet><![CDATA[Audit ]]></JobTitleFacet>
    <ExperienceLevels><![CDATA[PQ]]></ExperienceLevels>
    </job>
  <job>
  <job>
    <JobId>334</JobId>
    <Views>0</Views>
    <Apps>0</Apps>
    <Title><![CDATA[Something Else]]></Title>
    <JobTitleFacet><![CDATA[Audit ]]></JobTitleFacet>
    <ExperienceLevels><![CDATA[PQ]]></ExperienceLevels>
    </job>
  <job>
</jobs>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: XSLT and XPath is case-sensitive, so "Head Of Finance" (with an upper-case "O" in "Of") is not the same as "Head of Finance" (with a lower-case "o").

Comment: SMH!  Thank you!  Is there a way to be case insensitive as part of the select?  feel free to answer the Q so I can mark you as correct!

Comment: follow up - could I combine this with another statement like so:  `/jobs/job[Title[not(contains(text(),'Senior') or contains(text(),'Head of') or contains(text(),'Manager'))]] | /jobs/job[ExperienceLevels[normalize-space()='Entry Level' or normalize-space()='PQ' or normalize-space()='NQ']]`

Comment: Well, give it a go, and see what you get.... (And if it doesn't work as expected, feel free to ask a whole new question. It's a bit harder to read code just in comments). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because XSLT and XPath are case-sensitive, so "Head Of Finance" (with an upper-case "O" in "Of") is not the same as "Head of Finance" (with a lower-case "o").

If you are using XPATH 1.0, I believe you are restricted to using the `translate` function to translate upper-case letter to lower-case.

Try this....

```
/jobs/job[Title[not(
    contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrsuvwxyz') ,'senior') 
    or contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') ,'head of finance') 
    or contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') ,'manager'))]]
```

NOTE: In XPath 2.0, you may be able to write something like this:

```
jobs/job[Title[not(matches(text(), '(Senior)|(Head Of Finance)|(Manager)', 'i'))]]"
```